# Difficulty using the Matrix standard Ruby library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matrix

I am trying to use the standard Matrix ruby library. I have tried `include Matrix`, but that returns Uninitialised Constant, so I assume I have to put in my Gemfile

```
gem 'rubysl-e2mmap', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'rubysl-matrix', '~> 2.1'
```

When I bundle install, it works fine, but when I run `bundle exec rails c` I get the following error:

```
Could not find rubysl-e2mmap-2.0.0 in any of the sources
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `require 'matrix'` should do the trick, note that you give `require` a string.

Comment: I was actually doing ```include Matrix```, but ```require 'Matrix'``` does indeed do the trick thank you. I will edit my answer to ```include Matrix``` so it is of wider use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by `mu is too short`, I just needed to use `require 'matrix'`. I did not need to include the `rubysl-e2mmap` gem in my Gemfile.

Comment: You want `'matrix'`, not `'Matrix'`. I'm guessing you're using something with a case-insensitive file system so the difference doesn't matter on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, have changed it to 'matrix'